# Securing sensitive information in PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova

I have a number of REST API Keys (Google Places, etc) that I want to secure. Reading Google Groups and SO it seems obfuscation isn't a solution, neither is using the Keychain, so how do you suggest encrypting/securing sensitive information when the IPA package can just be unpacked and read? (I don't want to rewrite the application in Objective-C).

Comment: Do you have the option to host your own server that can act as an API proxy?

Comment: Thank you. What would stop someone from sniffing the transaction from the device and then abusing the REST api/calls directly to the proxy? I don't see how I can authenticate calls from a mobile device to the proxy, it's not as if I can whitelist the IP address etc!

Comment: The API key would only be transmitted between your proxy and Google Places. The device does not have it. You authenticate the device using your own independent schema. This is the same like a web service making API calls on behalf of a user.

Comment: Thank you. I understand, however, if the the mobile device is requesting myproxy.com?females=true&location=sanfrancisco for example, and the web services is returning the results in json, handling all the API key server side, nothings stops people from still sniffing the rest url and abusing the myproxy.com?females=true&location=sanfrancisco call, irrelevant of knowing the api key, as they don't need it now! How do I secure the handshake between the device and proxy so it approves calls just from my application?

Comment: You could have your own token-based scheme. Give every user a unique ID, obtained by login to your service. Also, sniffing can be prevented by using HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks Thilo, if you submit the API proxy as answer I'll choose it as this is the method I'm going to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the option of hosting a web service yourself, you can have the device talk to your own server instead of Google's. It would act as a proxy: The device authenticates to your service using a scheme of your choosing and never gets to see the API key, which rests securely on your servers. The process is very similar to how it would work on a web site (where also the browser does not talk to the backend service provider directly, but the web server does it on its behalf).