# How to protect sensitive data in Phonegap?

Tags: cordova, encryption

If I write keys in JavaScript source code，then anyone can get read the key. How to protect sensitive data in Phonegap?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Securing sensitive information in PhoneGap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153367/securing-sensitive-information-in-phonegap)

Comment: It's a good idea,but it depend on server, is there any client method to solve it?