# Loading protected property/value pair in Cordova?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugin-proguard

Long story short, I'm trying to add "protected" data and load them in my Cordova app. The type of data could be for instance a username and password for accessing a remote resource. That data should not be readable even if someone unpacks the app.

I'd like to basically add something like

```
<param name="username" value="admin">
<param name="password" value="password">
...
```

to my config.xml so it ends up being encrypted/protected in the manifest/plist.info (via proguard?) depending on the platform, and loadable in clear within the app.

Doable? How? Any direction?

**Edit:** How about using **PROGUARD** with Cordova and store sensitive info in the native code (Java/Swift)?

Thanks

Comment: if you decide to use proguard you can use this cordova-plugin-proguard https://alfilatov.com/posts/how-to-setup-proguard-in-cordova-application/

Answer (score 0):

Cordova says:

> Do not cache sensitive data
>   If usernames, password, geolocation information, and other sensitive data is cached, then it could potentially be retrieved later by an unauthorized user or application.

What is the purpose of keeping this data there? If you have security problems accessing the data, you can use an encryption library. Here is the kind of thing you can see at work: http://point-at-infinity.org/jsaes/

I hope the matter is correct. :)

Edited : 
By the way you can use this plugin https://github.com/Crypho/cordova-plugin-secure-storage

Comment: Where do I store the key of the encryption then? Encrypting data and storing the key in clear in the code is just dumb? Something I don't get?

Comment: You can check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153367/securing-sensitive-information-in-phonegap

Comment: Well the answer is basically you can't store it in the app... What about using proguard and store the key in the native layer?

Comment: In fact we need to keep sensitive data on the server side and we do not mind communicating them with encrypted OAuth. If discovery is not simple, you can also keep LocalStorage encrypted. And when you need to value, get encrypted from localstorage and decrypt it.

Comment: If you are going to use the Android version you may be proguard but i did not say it to be a solution in cordova

Comment: By the way you can use this plugin https://github.com/Crypho/cordova-plugin-secure-storage